# Search Query with Nest ElasticSearch having AND operator

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to search following text:

"women held" (note " " is added for text representation)

What I need from the above text is all the item that contains the "women" and "held" words from the field stored in the elastic index.

What I tried was:

```
 string searchText = "women held";
 var filterQuery = Query<T>.Terms("summaryText", searchText.Split(' '));
 var result = Client.Search<T>(s => s.Index(IndexName).Query(filterQuery).Size(1000));
```

But the above query result in getting either of the item as "Women" Or "held" from the "summaryText" field but what I want is "women and held" i.e. both text to be present in "summaryText" field.

Please let me know if this make sense.
I have tried many combination but still haven't succeeded.
Does anyone from  Nest Guru can help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I got as solution, hope it would help anyone trying the similar ANDing search.
Well not an elegant way but works for me:

```
string searchText = "women held";
string[] splitSearch = searchText.Split(' ');
List<QueryContainer> searchQueryList = new List<QueryContainer>();
foreach(var strText in splitSearch)
{
   searchQueryList.Add(Query<T>.Term("summaryText", strText));
}

var filterQuery = Query<T>.Bool(b=> b.Must(searchQueryList.ToArray()));
var result = Client.Search<T>(s => s.Index(IndexName).Query(filterQuery).Size(1000));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the exact match for "woman held" on a field then do not split the string:

```cs
string searchText = "women held";
var filterQuery = Query<T>.Terms("summaryText", searchText);
var result = Client.Search<T>(s => s.Index(IndexName).Query(filterQuery).Size(1000));
```

If what you are looking for is a "contains" functionality, then you need to use a [regexp](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) query (but has a performance overhead if your data is huge):

```cs
SearchDescriptor<T> descriptor = new SearchDescriptor<T>();
descriptor = descriptor.Index(IndexName).Size(1000)
    .Query(query => query
        .Regexp(r => r.OnField("summaryText").Value(".*" + "woman held" + ".*")));
var result = ElasticClient().Search<T>(s => descriptor);
```

Comment: Thanks @gsk thats a good hack, but my index is really huge having wild card regex would definitely slows the execution. Just now I tried something else and it worked. Not sure why Nest .Net dont provide that. I'll post as an answer.